# Appium : How many packages does installation need?

Tags: node.js, npm, appium, package

I'm just trying to install latest (1.6.3) version of appium by using npm.

I'm not sure if the installation works quite fine because really a lot of different packages are getting downloaded by npm.
I'm not sure if all these packages are really needed by appium and how to restrict this...

For example: packages like `ncp`, `method-override` or `proxy-addr` are fetched by npm.

Can anyone help? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think those are installed by default, so don't worry about that ! More packages better than less packages.
Try to verify by appium doctor :

```
$ npm install -g appium-doctor
$ appium-doctor
```

[Appium installation](https://nishantverma.gitbooks.io/appium-for-android/content/install_appium_via_source.html)

Comment: Okay. Seems legit. Found a post that is about this topic [link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15210).